# Error: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable

Tags: node.js, docker, google-cloud-run, cloud-run-emulator

I'm trying to deploy my API to Cloud Run but I'm stuck with this error

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /src
COPY package.json package*.json ./
RUN npm install --omit=dev
COPY . .
CMD [ "npm", "execute" ]
```

This are my package.json scripts

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "env-cmd -x -f ./src/config/env/.env.local nodemon ./src/index.js",
    "deploy:dev": "env-cmd -x -f ./src/config/env/.env.dev ./deploy.sh",
    "execute": "env-cmd -x -f ./src/config/env/.env.dev node ./src/index.js"
  },
```

This is my index.js

```
const api = require("../src/config/config");

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
console.log("Puerto => ", port);
api.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Rest API started succesfully`);
});
```

This is my config file (I'm working with firebase)

```
const express = require("express");

//  Config
const api = express();
api.use(express.json());

//  Routes
api.use(require("../routes/start.routes.js"));

module.exports = api;
```

And I have a .env file with the PORT variable

```
PORT=8080
```

And these are the commands I execute

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/$GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID/api --project=$GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID

gcloud run deploy api --image gcr.io/$GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID/api --port 8080 --platform managed --region us-central1 --allow-unauthenticated --project=$GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID
```

I have followed every tip about similar questions but none has worked for me

I checked logs and they only expose the description I referred in the beginning.
I try to run my project locally with Cloud Run Emulator, it does not work but I don't get enough info to figure out what's wrong. I don't even understand why in the docker container I see several ports except 8080 which is the one the app should listen on and then says the deploy process failed

I'm using windows 11

My API works fine locally if I run `npm run start`

[image: Docker container]

Comment: I have the same problem when running Firebase functions.

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly does indicate that there is an issue with the specific defined incoming HTTP requests ports and the container is failing to listen on the expected port.The official document [Cloud Run container contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#port) has these mentioned to meet these requirements in order to operate properly.
In Node.js ,your js should define as below:
`const port = process.env.PORT || 8080; app.listen(port, () => { console.log('Hello listening port', port); });`
You may check if your container is listening on all network interfaces once by denoting port as `0.0.0.0` and see if that works.You may also want to confirm if  your container image is compiled for 64-bit Linux as expected by the container runtime contract.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to troubleshoot the issue**

> 1. Check the logs of your Cloud Run service using the command in cloudshell

```
gcloud logs read --project $GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID --service api --limit 100

//You can adjust the --limit flag to show more or fewer log entries.
```

> 2.Check the logs of your container If there is any problem with the container itself, you will get using that command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 gcr.io/$GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID/api
```

that command starts your container and map port 8080 inside the container to your local machine's port 8080. Access your app at http://localhost:8080. Check the console output for any errors with the container.

> 3. Check your Cloud Run configuration

> 4. Check your application code

in your index.js  file Make sure the api.listen() function is using a port variable that is set to the value of the PORT environment variable:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
api.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Rest API started successfully`);
});
```

> 5 check  your firewall settings

some times firewall blocks traffic to port 8080.
you can check the firewall rules in the Google Cloud Console

using that step you find the issues and if you can't find the issue then reach out to the Cloud Run support team for further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using nodemon:

the presence of nodemon could potentially be causing the issue. Nodemon is a tool used to monitor changes in your source code and automatically restart the server during development. However, when deploying to Cloud Run as a job, you shouldn't have a server that listens on a port.

If your app is using nodemon, it might be starting a development server that listens on a port, which is not suitable for Cloud Run jobs. To address this, you would need to ensure that your deployment process doesn't involve using nodemon or starting a server. Instead, your app should execute its task and then exit, without attempting to listen on a port.

It took me hours to realize this was causing my issue. I'm not saying it's the same for you but I couldn't find a thing around it on the internet so I decided to share just in case anybody else ran into this. Simple fix was to remove the dependency.